# NLTK reuters datasets not found

Tags: python, nltk, reuters

I downloaded Reuters dataset from nltk using the following command:

```
import nltk
nltk.download('reuters')
```

I got a confirmation that the datset was downloaded and I can see the it under "C:/Users/username/AppData/Roaming/nltk_data".

However, when I want to read the dataset, python can't see it! I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\username\python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\externals\cloudpickle\cloudpickle.py:47: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
  import imp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\util.py", line 80, in __load
    try: root = nltk.data.find('{}/{}'.format(self.subdir, zip_name))
  File "C:\Users\username\python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 675, in find
    raise LookupError(resource_not_found)
LookupError: 
**********************************************************************
  Resource [93mreuters[0m not found.
  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:

  [31m>>> import nltk
  >>> nltk.download('reuters')
  [0m
  Searched in:
    - 'C:\\Users\\username/nltk_data'
    - 'C:\\nltk_data'
    - 'D:\\nltk_data'
    - 'E:\\nltk_data'
    - 'C:\\Users\\username\\python\\Python37-32\\nltk_data'
    - 'C:\\Users\\username\\python\\Python37-32\\share\\nltk_data'
    - 'C:\\Users\\username\\python\\Python37-32\\lib\\nltk_data'
    - 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Roaming\\nltk_data'
*******
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\username\eclipse-workspace\ML\src\PAs\pa2\Test.py", line 17, in <module>
        from commons import util, datasets, runClassifier, mlGraphics
      File "C:\Users\username\eclipse-workspace\ML\src\commons\datasets.py", line 258, in <module>
        class Reuters:
      File "C:\Users\username\eclipse-workspace\ML\src\commons\datasets.py", line 259, in Reuters
        documents = reuters.fileids()
      File "C:\Users\username\python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\util.py", line 116, in __getattr__
        self.__load()
      File "C:\Users\username\python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\util.py", line 81, in __load
        except LookupError: raise e
      File "C:\Users\username\python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\util.py", line 78, in __load
        root = nltk.data.find('{}/{}'.format(self.subdir, self.__name))
      File "C:\Users\username\python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 675, in find
        raise LookupError(resource_not_found)
    LookupError: 
    *********
      Resource [93mreuters[0m not found.
      Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:
      [31m>>> import nltk
      >>> nltk.download('reuters')
      [0m
      Searched in:
        - 'C:\\Users\\username/nltk_data'
        - 'C:\\nltk_data'
        - 'D:\\nltk_data'
        - 'E:\\nltk_data'
        - 'C:\\Users\\username\\python\\Python37-32\\nltk_data'
        - 'C:\\Users\\username\\python\\Python37-32\\share\\nltk_data'
        - 'C:\\Users\\username\\python\\Python37-32\\lib\\nltk_data'
        -C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Roaming\\nltk_data'
```

I tried to create manually a directory "C:/Users/username/nltk_data" and paste the reuters.zip there, but that didn't help!
When I download it again using nltk.download(), it shows me the following:

```
[nltk_data] Downloading package reuters to C:\Users\username/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Package reuters is already up-to-date!
```

Any hints?
I also wondering why the paths printed by python contain slashes `/`and backslashes `\` at the same time?

Comment: did you download corpus with nltk.downloader or manually?

Comment: I downloaded it with the nltk.downloader as mentioned in the beginning of the post

Comment: are you using vim?

Comment: I downloaded the corpus from both eclipse (PyDev plugin for python) and Windows command line.

Comment: it looks like python 3.7. version "bug", can you run same code on older version of python, eg. 3.6.5.?

Comment: but first, try to replace import imp with import importlib

Comment: can you post this as an answer so I can mark it as the solution?

Comment: Go to 'C:/Users/username/AppData/Roaming/nltk_data' and unzip the file and then load it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `imp` module is deprecated while using `nltk` with `python 3.7`, use `import importlib` instead of `import imp`, or try to run code with older version of `python`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just to go to a folder where corpus is downloaded and just unzip an archive.
To see where corpus was downloaded:

> > nltk.download('reuters')
> >
> > > [nltk_data] Downloading package reuters to /home/denys/nltk_data...
> > >       [nltk_data]   Package reuters is already up-to-date!

Answer (score -3):

this is my code. You can get help accordingly

```
import nltk
#nltk.download('punkt')
#nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')
var = open("e:\Assignment\my_file.txt","r") #open file
lines = var.read() #read all lines
sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(lines) #tokenize sentences
nouns = [] #empty to array to hold all nouns

for sentence in sentences:
     for word,pos in nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize(str(sentence))):
         if (pos == 'NN' or pos == 'NNP' or pos == 'NNS' or pos == 'NNPS'):
             nouns.append(word)


print (nouns)
```

Comment: here I am going to extract nouns using NLTK

Comment: how is this solving his problem?

Comment: he can use his file name instead of my file.. and NLTK will work

Comment: actually he has to use reuters dataset which is not available here